# Android studio cant find some settings in layouts attributes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I created a layout file for recycler view, but I can't find most of the required settings for the views in the **attributes**.I can't even set the *textSize* in the attributes!
So i have to set them by xml code:
(Even when writing the code, AndroidStudio does not offer suggestions)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/material_dynamic_primary70"
            app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
            app:cardElevation="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout></layout>
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Yep I do it now.

Comment: Have you set the 'Power Save, mode on File Tab ??

Comment: sorry I cant understand..I just did whatever I was doing before, but this time I ran into this problem

Comment: it is just a Cache Issue, Just Clean and Rebuild your code followed by Invalid Cache-Restart and Gradle Sync.

Answer (score 0):

just press **File -> uncheck the Power save mode** -> Restart Android Studio

Power save mode is second last option available in file menu.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ,But it was already unchecked